# nvd3 pie chart says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/pXitfqb8K2IbxOHXw0uL?p=preview

Is it logging right values, but not building pie chart.
Instead, I can see the following in logs

```
nvd pie -  {"values":[{"parent":"Food","amount":116.1},{"parent":"Home","amount":670.14},{"parent":"Travel","amount":365.24},{"parent":"Taxes","amount":31.240000000000002},{"parent":"Entertainment","amount":13.24}]} script.js:166
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined nv.d3.js:9623
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at line 9623 from nv.d3.js, you will find that the map method is called on the first element of an array and your data is an object.

What you need to do, is to encapsulate your values inside of a 1 element array:

```
var data = [{ 
  key : "",
  values : [{"parent":"Food","amount":116.1},{"parent":"Home","amount":670.14},{"parent":"Travel","amount":365.24},{"parent":"Taxes","amount":31.240000000000002},{"parent":"Entertainment","amount":13.24}] 
}];
```

Comment: I believe this a bug in NVd3's pie chart.  It should be using the supplied values method to access the values rather then assuming it's an array. But this workaround is good, until some one gets around to patching it.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug simce even in the examples, data is encapsulated in a single element array. I don't know why it was designed like this.

Comment: When I read the source for pie.js, i saw a values accessor, which PieChart.js should use to access the array you wish to use. I believe   @daydreamer should be able to say chart.values(function(d){ return d.values;}) if that's the array he wanted to return.  Maybe, what I'm seeing a something completely unrelated. :]

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for a while, mainly because I started from the live examples on the nvd3.org site.

It turns out the data format in the examples on the live site differs to that in the examples bundled with the core nvd3 download.

In the pie.html example in the download the data is specified as follows:

```
var testdata = [
{ 
  key: "One",
  y: 5
},
{ 
  key: "Two",
  y: 2
},
{ 
  key: "Three",
  y: 9
}
];
```

Then when passing the data through it's wrapped in an unnamed/keyed array ...

```
d3...datum([testdata])....
```

This format works fine for me.

Comment: I've been searching for this for about 8 hours ... you made my day! thx a lot, cheerioh!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling through many hours, I was able to fix this issue.

Please look at http://plnkr.co/edit/qJnZzBS4ZOUtD2q9FV11?p=preview to see how it works